# Is there any way to wait for button clicks without an EventHandler?

Tags: java, button, javafx, int, return

Is there any way I can return a certain integer when the button "ok" is pressed, and return another number if the exit button in the top right corner is pressed?

**EDIT:** This is just a method taken out from a larger class. Please assume that the window shows. What I am asking for is the code that secures the return of either two numbers, but only if a button is pressed.

---

```
public static int showMessageDialog(String title, String object_message){
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setMinHeight(150);
    stage.setMinWidth(250);
    stage.setTitle(title);

    ok = new Button("OK");

    gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    gridPane.setVgap(30);

    message = new Text(object_message);
    gridPane.addColumn(0, message, ok);
    scene = new Scene(gridPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: JavaFX 8u40 has in-built [Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) and [Alerts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html), which can return values.  You may wish to use them, [as taught in this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/), instead of writing your own.

Comment: Aye, I know I can use them. But I need to write my own as I need special cases later. Just trying to do it on a simpler, easier comparable form

Comment: The problem with using EventHandler, is that I can't seem to use it to return any value to the call of this method. I might be overseeing something here, so I would love to know how to use it if you can think of a way to solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it on your own, just make the `Stage` modal and use `showAndWait` instead of `show` to block the calling Thread until the `Stage` gets closed:

```
public static int showMessageDialog(String title, String object_message){
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setMinHeight(150);
    stage.setMinWidth(250);
    stage.setTitle(title);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    IntegerProperty returnCode = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

    ok = new Button("OK");
    ok.setOnAction(ev -> {returnCode.set(1); stage.close();});

    gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    gridPane.setVgap(30);

    message = new Text(object_message);
    gridPane.addColumn(0, message, ok);
    scene = new Scene(gridPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.showAndWait();

    return returnCode.get();
}
```

Comment: @Adrian Glad to help and if this answers your question, please "accept" it ;-)